# Unknown packaging: hpi @ io.jenkins.plugins Error When Trying to Build Jenkins Plugin with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create jenkins plugin from maven archetype, and using 'Hello-world' jenkins plugin template. However after generating plugin from maven archetype, when I am running

`mvn verify`

I'm getting the below error

The project has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:3.37 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler:jar:1747.v9580b_2f1d80b (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler:jar:1747.v9580b_2f1d80b from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org (https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: hpi @ io.jenkins.plugins:demo:${revision}${changelist},

My pom.xml is below, it is not modified at all, and same as it was generated from archetype

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

When I run it on a different personal pc, and it was BUILD SUCCESS, but getting this error on my work pc. There is no difference in Java Version/ Maven version/ plugin archetype version in both cases.

I tried multiple different solutions.

1. I tried to add certificates for repo.jenkins-ci.org following instructions from https://apisero.com/how-to-resolve-pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-issue/ and certificate was added successfully. Still the error persists.
2. I tried to modify seetings.xml as described here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial , but it didn't resolve the issue either.
3. I tried to get the jar org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler:jar:1747.v9580b_2f1d80b manually and put it in my .m2/repository, after that I get couple of more .jar and .hpi files absent error.

Could not resolve dependencies for project io.jenkins.plugins:demo:hpi:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps:jar:3536.vb_8a_6628079d5 (absent), io.jenkins.plugins:ionicons-api:jar:31.v4757b_6987003 (absent), org.jenkins-ci.plugins:scm-api:jar:621.vda_a_b_055e58f7 (absent), com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:jar:3536.vb_8a_6628079d5 (absent), io.jenkins.plugins:lib-durable-task:jar:25.v6c906af81ee2 (absent), org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:jar:2.361.4 (absent), org.jenkins-ci.main:cli:jar:2.361.4 (absent), org.jenkins-ci.main:remoting:jar:3044.vb_940a_a_e4f72e (absent), commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1-jenkins-3 (absent), org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.18-kohsuke-1 (absent), org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler:jar:1711.1713.vc400cfb_5597a_ (absent), org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler-adjunct-codemirror:jar:1.3 (absent), org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-war:war:2.361.4 (absent), org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-test-harness:jar:1903.vf505ecb_63589 (absent), org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-test-harness-htmlunit:jar:127.v28144890db_46 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps:jar:3536.vb_8a_6628079d5 from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org (https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Also it doesn't seem like https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/ url is blocked, because I can see in log other .jar or pom files are being downloaded and transferred from this url. I am only getting this error for few particular .jar and .hpi which is not being downloaded, and can't find any useful solution. Please help.